# MarkLogic- Java Search Query By Example 'not' operator

Tags: java, marklogic

For MarkLogic Query-By-Example, I can search for all entries that contains the specific email address like this:

```
{
 "$query":
   {
      "emailAddress":"kdm@yahoo.com"
   }
}
```

My question is how can you negate this search, for this specific example, how can I find all the results that does NOT contain emailAddress with value: 'kdm@yahoo.com'  ? Is there a not operator for MarkLogic Query By Example JSON format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$not` or `$nor`: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe mentions `$nor`, but looking at `qbe-model.xqy` I think that's a typo and it should be `$not`.

There's also a `$ne` for range query, in case that helps.